# Source of saying: नित्यं एकमनस्कौ तौ (Nithyam Ekamanaskou tou)

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, dvaita, madhvacharya, bhima

In [this video](https://youtu.be/WvpBMQt5oK0?t=1855s), a Swamiji belonging to Shri Madhwacharya order of Sannyasis, say that Lord Krishna and Bhima had the same mindset and same opinons.

He says in Sanskrit,

> नित्यं एकमनस्कौ तौ
> They both are always one minded

What is the source of this saying? Is it from Mahabharata?

Comment: Why is this downvoted. Explain please